# Spans in several lines

Tags: html, css

I have several blocks with two spans inside of each block

```
<span class='block black'>
  <span class='line1 blue'>Text</span>
  <span class='line2 red'>text-text-texttt</span>
</span>
....
<span class='block black'>
  <span class='line1 blue'>text-text-text-text-text</span>
  <span class='line2 red'>Texe</span>
</span>
```

and I would like to format them using CSS in the following way

[image]

Answer (score 4):

You can try this

```
span.block.black {
   display: inline-block;
}

span.block.blue, span.block.red {   
   display: block;
}
```

inline-block : This value causes an element to generate an inline-level block container. The inside of an inline-block is formatted as a block box, and the element itself is formatted as an atomic inline-level box

Source (w3.org) : http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visuren.html

Comment: Included w3.org reference, and removed the previous reference. Thanks

Comment: Thanks for making it safe for new devs... `:)`

Comment: Thanks to you @PraveenKumar for pointing out. Have a good day !

Answer (score 2):

Just add display property value of `inline-block` to `.block-black` to  have them aligned side by side, then add display  property value of `block` to the inner spans to have them take up the full width of .block-black while stacking on each other.

```css
.block-black {
    display: block;
    width: auto;
    display: inline-block;
      border: solid 5px black;
    padding: 10px;

}

.block-black:last-of-type {

    margin-top: 15px;
}

.block-black span {
    width: 100%;
    display: inline-block;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
}

.block-black span:first-of-type {
border: solid 5px blue;
}
.block-black span:last-of-type {
border: solid 5px red;
}
```

```html
<span class='block-black'>
  <span class='line1 blue'>Text</span>
  <span class='line2 red'>text-text-texttt</span>   
</span>

<span class='block-black'>
  <span class='line1 blue'>Text</span>
  <span class='line2 red'>text-text-texttt</span>   
</span>


<br>
    
<span class='block-black'>
  <span class='line1 blue'>text-text-text-text-text</span>
  <span class='line2 red'>Texe</span>
</span>
```

**Note:** Adjust the CSS property values to achieve desired results.